# Should we ask and answer ourselves the "usually asked questions" before we go public?

Tags: discussion

From our experiences, we know the frequently asked questions (*but not easy or basic*) about Islam by people. Is it a good idea to ask them and answer it ourselves with the best answers beforehand? Or should we wait for others to ask it?

In my opinion, those answers will attract more traffic.

Comment: why not if they are good questions? :)

Comment: @Kaveh See my answer

Comment: @Dynamic, of course we should only ask questions we care about but I don't see it as a no to what Ershad is suggesting. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, be really careful about cracking open the *textbook-of-oft-asked-questions*. Canned questions have a tendency to come across as staid and forced, and they'll already have been asked on every other site on the subject. From all early indications, this site  will have no trouble gaining genuine, organic participation from people who are actually *having* these problems.

***That's*** how to keep the questions interesting and intriguing.

So, try not to "seed" your site too much or the whole thing is going to look conspicuously-boring and contrived. That will not make for an interesting site.

> [The act of "seeding" a site] suggests to me that we’re coming up with questions just for the sake of asking questions. My concern is, if people feel that the author doesn’t really care about the answer, the whole exercise would likely be perceived as a waste of time.
>
> *— from [**Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)*

Answer (score 2):

Keeping it short:

***No. We should only ask questions if you actually have the question. Not just to ask them***

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we need to think "on behalf" of other people. Stackexchange has a good system set up - the questions that need to get asked will get asked. There's no need to pre-empt or manipulate the system. The system works best when everyone acts on their own, asks questions they genuinely have, and answers questions they have expertise about.