# Are there any examples of self-answered Q&A's on this site?

Tags: discussion

So I posted up a self-answered Q&A, mainly in a bid to contribute information that I did not find present on the site:

[What are the Keys of the Unseen?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39483/13732)

Judging by some of the comments, this seems like a rarity on the site.

***Is there no precedent for self-answered Q&A's on the site?***

---

***For what it's worth...***

I'll quote the [Help](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) to justify this kind of format:

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>
> Yes! Stack Exchange [has always explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: This one https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29759/13438 and some other questions of mine. And i've seen many of this kind in the early days of ISE.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few examples, particularly from the early days of the site (e.g. [What is Sunnah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/428/22)), but it's generally not something that we see done here.

There's nothing particularly wrong with the practice — as you mention this is something that's encouraged across the network — but many of the cases where it *was* used it was used for the wrong reasons so I think it's typically met with a general disdain.

In particular, [textbook FAQ-style questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/175/22) and leading questions [intended to promote/soapbox a particular point of view](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/258/22) were rather common, and are explicitly discouraged. We want questions that are honestly interesting and organic, not just shoehorned excuses to push information that nobody's actually asking about.

I see nothing wrong with it if it's an honest question you (or someone else) actually had, and you've already found the answer want to document it here: That's basically the whole point of the self-answer feature. As long as it's a good question and a good answer, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/islam/query/667279/self-answered-questions), yours is the 48-th case of someone answering their own question on the same day.

In 2017 there have been these examples thus far:

- [Should we say two takbeer on the very moment we join the Imam during congregration?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38563/17163)
- [Were the moral and ethical laws of modern Europe borrowed from the Quran?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39203/17163) (now deleted)
- [On what basis are the Sahaba considered trustworthy narrators of Hadeeth?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39381/17163) [which is your one]

In 2016 there were these examples:

- [Haidth on performing ruqyah and being brought into account on judgement day](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36230/17163)
- [Is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30156/17163)
- [Why people may be born disabled?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30036/17163)